# Creating a cylinder with an SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create an SVG cylinder like in the image below, but it doesn't work. This is what I tried so far:

```html
<svg>
   <path d=" M 0 20 0 200 M 0 200 C 0 200, 130 250, 260 200 M 260 200 260 20 M 260 20 C 260 0, 130 50, 0 20 M 0 20 C 0 20, 130 -50, 260 20" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="#84D3DB"/>
</svg>
```

---

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Download an SVG drawing tool such as Inkscape and draw whatever you want.

Comment: If it isn't single path how you will fill background color in main body?

Comment: @Paulie_D Great example!!! but if I add `fill:red;` it isn't filled properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilise a single path using arcs

```css
svg {
  height:90vh;
  margin:1em auto; 
  display: block;
  stroke-width:1;
  fill:lightblue;
  border:1px solid green;
}

svg:hover path {
  fill:lightgreen
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <path d="
             M2,50
             A50,10 0 0,0 98,50
             A50,10 0 0,0 2,50
             L2,75
             A50,10,0 0,0 98,75
             L98,50             
             "
          style="stroke:#660000;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you provide a path with relative variables depending on cylinder_middle_x, cylinder_middle_y,cylinder_l,cylinder_r ?